# WPF grid column def auto always clipping from right

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app which has a grid with 2 columns set to * and auto. The issue is when I reduce the size of the window the children in second column are getting clipped from right instead of left. I expect them to clip from left because I have set the horizontal alignment to right.
Is there a way we can clip the second column elements from left?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me" Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <Label Content="abcdef" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <Label x:Name="mLog"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="click me" Width="150"/>
        <Label Content="abcdef" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: In your example the clipping doesn't happen on the ```DockPanel``` but on the surrounding ```Grid```. With the 2nd column ```Width``` set to ```Auto``` the column will always be wide enough to hold all contents and prevent any clipping done on them. However the ```Grid```will now be bigger than the Window and is being clipped from the right. You could set the ```HorizontalAlignment```property of the ```Grid``` to right, but that would mean you lose your column to the left.

Comment: @SSchulze Oops: at FIRST I though your answer is correct: the Grid is just too big for the Window; but it is not! If you add the numbers then it SEEMS that the content SHOULD all fit. I believe it has to do with the "mLog" Label taking the remaining DockPanel space, and the outer layout of the Grid is now confused. Why doesn't the "mLog" Label appear at all?

Comment: @StevenCoco i don't understand. The point is that if you resize the window there isn't enough space to fit the content and OP doesn't want the right side to be clipped first. This is certainly caused by the grid not sizing with the window due to its auto column. Also the mLog label doesn't have content so that's why it's not displayed at all.

Comment: @SSchulze Sorry twice! I in fact do think you are correct! The given layout will clip that way, and it's correct for that layout. It simply needs a different layout that is correct for a different desired alignment/clipping ... Something like Jannne Matikainen's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="60"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me" Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <Label Content="abcdef" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            <Label x:Name="mLog"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="click me" Width="150"/>
        <Label Content="abcdef" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me" Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <Label Content="abcdef" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <Label x:Name="mLog"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="click me"/>
            <Label Content="abcdef" Width="200" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

i deleted the last button width property.

output:
[image: wpf grid]

Comment: How does your answer fix the issue, my button in the right column is still getting smaller when I reduce the window size.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you are trying to make 3 column layout with 1 button on either side and 1 middle lane for content.

So you could try something like this, where all your content are in same grid with different z-index and horizontal alignments, now when you resize the window the label stays in middle and the buttons "clip behind" the label content from the right and the left.

```
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="click me" Width="150" />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="click me" Width="150" />
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="abcdef" Width="200" Background="White" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Without further info from OP as to exactly what their desired layout is, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your DockPanel, HorizontalAlignment only help when the Width of the DockPanel is bigger than total Width of all its children. The Button and the Label have fixed size 200 and 150 and I believe the behavior of WPF will clip element from the left.

The first tricky way is having the DockPanel fill both columns, when the Grid go smaller, a part of the DockPanel will go under the content on the first column giving the feel like it is clipped from the left.

```
 <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="60"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
         <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me 2" Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
         <Label Content="abcdef 2" Width="200" />
         <Label x:Name="mLog" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
     </DockPanel>
     <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me 1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
     <Label Content="abcdef 1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
 </Grid>
```

Another proper way is using another Grid instead of DockPanel, make sure we have the first column fill the space so that will go down size along with the container.

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="click me" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="150"/>
        <Label Content="abcdef" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Label x:Name="mLog"/>
    </Grid>
```